# ROC curve and perfcurve function

Tags: roc

I have a confusion about ROC curve and hopefully you can help me!

To plot ROC, i was naively using a simple command as plot(False_alarm_rate,Hit_rate,'-'). But, it is not exactly the  same as **perfcurve** plot.  To use this function, i wrote the following script

```
Q=reshape([Hit_rate False_alarm_rate],[],1);
      Labels=[]; Labels = ones(size(Q,1),1);
      Labels(end/2+1:end) = 0; 
      PosClass = 1;
      X=[];Y=[];
      [X Y T,AUC] = perfcurve(Labels,Q,PosClass);
      figure, plot(X,Y,'r') % ROC
```

could you please tell me , what i am missing here?

- BTW, can we calculate d-prime from output of perfcurve?

thanks in advance,
Karlo

Answer (score 0):

ROC is basically sensitivity vs specificity curve.Its very easy and time consuming. Hope I can help you if I get below details:
1.what type of data you are using?
2.Which parameter of the data you want in curve?
3.Did you ever tried to plot ROC using sensitivity and specificity data?

Comment: Dear Leone, thanks for your answer.  I think, my confusion is coming from type of test.  I ran a a memory study with several participants. Each subject was observing a sequence of objects.He/she has to identify a specific object. hit rate defined based on his/her success to identify target object and false alarm  rate calculated based on identifying non target object as target.  I don't have a distribution of  hit rate and false alarm rate. only two value for each subject.   I have to redefine my question, is it possible to have d' or roc curve for each subject?

Comment: I think its impossible.